# zendframework2 avoid or improve error router no match logs

Tags: php, zend-framework2

on my logs on data/log/....log

I found many:

```
[17-Nov-2014 10:22:24] Dispatch ERROR: error-router-no-match
[17-Nov-2014 10:22:24] Dispatch ERROR: error-router-no-match
[17-Nov-2014 10:23:01] Dispatch ERROR: error-controller-not-found
[17-Nov-2014 10:23:01] Dispatch ERROR: error-controller-not-found
```

I wish i can either get rid of them or show more info from where these hits or to where these hits are being made so i can correct things.

How this works and is there a established way to do this and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably, these logs are generated by some sort of Bootstrap code (maybe in module/Application/Module.php or any other appropriate place). You need to find that code and add more information to the logging service.